# Trying to extract text using CHARINDEX ()- 1 but getting an error

Tags: t-sql

I have a column with Names, and I am trying to split the column into First and Last Name using Text functions such as LEFT/SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX.

Data in the column:

| Name |
| --- |
| Yang, Jon |
| Huang, Eugene |
| Torres, Ruben |
| Zhu, Christy |
| Johnson, Elizabeth |

Everything works fine as long as I use this code:

```
SELECT 
    [Name]
    --,LEFT([Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [Name])) AS FirstName
    ,SUBSTRING([Name], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Name] )) AS FirstName
FROM 
    DataModeling.Customer
```

But the problem arises when I try to subtract 1 from CHARINDEX to exclude the Comma from the result and it throws this error:
[image]

I have done this operation many times in Excel so trying to replicate it with TSQL. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong is helpful.

Comment: You get that error when `CHARINDEX(' ', [Name] )` return `0`. So minus `1` will make it negative and it is invalid value for `substring()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked, I didn't realize there were some blanks towards the bottom, should have been more meticulous. Do you want to post this as an answer I will mark that as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error when CHARINDEX(' ', [Name] ) return 0. So minus 1 will make it negative and it is invalid value for substring()

You can use `CASE` expression to check the return value from `CHARINDEX()` and return the correct value to `substring()`

Or, you can "cheat" by using

```
CHARINDEX( ' ', [Name] + ' ' )
```

So `CHARINDEX()` will always return a value that is more than 0